# Toggling a function that depends on a button state?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to turn a button-click into a toggle that enables or disables a function, depending on its state. The function allows the enter key to be used for a form submission.

```
var enterToggle = true;
function enterToggleListener(elem) {
  enterKeyPress();
  elem.click(function() {
    enterToggle = !enterToggle;
    console.log('enter-toggle clicked')
    if (enterToggle === false) {
      console.log('enter toggle false')
      // What do I need to add here to stop 'enterKeyPress()'?
    } else {
      console.log('enter toggle true')
      enterKeyPress();
    }
  });
}

function enterKeyPress() {
  $('#noteText').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
      $('#noteButton').click();
    }
  });
}

enterToggleListener($('#toggle-button'));
```

What I don't understand is how to stop the `enterKeyPress()` function when `enterToggle` is false. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Cleaned-up code, with @James Montagne's answer added

```
var enterToggle = true;
function enterToggleListener(elem) {
  elem.click(function() {
    enterToggle = !enterToggle;
    if (enterToggle === false) {
      $('#enter-toggle').text('Enter key saves note (OFF)')
    } else {
      $('#enter-toggle').text('Enter key saves note (ON)')
    }
  });
}

function enterKeyPress() {
  $('#noteText').keypress(function(e){
    if(enterToggle && e.which == 13){
      $('#noteButton').click();
    }
  });
}

enterKeyPress();
enterToggleListener($('#enter-toggle'));
```

Comment: You shouldn't bind events inside of other event handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function enterKeyPress() {
    $('#noteText').keypress(function(e){
        if(enterToggle && e.which == 13){
            $('#noteButton').click();
        }
    });
}
```

You can simply check the value of the variable within your handler.  This way you don't need to keep adding and removing the handler as seems to be your current approach.

However, if you must add and remove for some reason, you would use [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/).